# Higher Order Functions on Python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I am given a list of functions and asked to define `plus(x,y)` with `add1` and `repeated`. `plus` is a function that takes in two numbers and returns the total. However, I cannot get any output with my definition. It just gives the name of the function. Any help is appreciated!

```
add1 = lambda x: x + 1

def compose(f, g):
return lambda x: f(g(x))

def repeated(f, n):
    if n == 0:
        return lambda x: x
    else:
        return compose(f, repeated(f, n - 1)) 

def plus(x, y):
    return repeated(add1, y)
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the functions?

Comment: Where do you use `x` in `plus`?

Comment: the test cases are plus() with any two integers, plus(1,3), plus(2,5) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an interesting way to do addition. It works quite well, you just missed one thing. `Repeated` returns a function which will give the sum, not the sum itself. So you just have to call `repeated(add1, y)` on `x` like this

```
def plus(x, y):
    return repeated(add1, y)(x)
```

The rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The detail is that `plus` returns a function and that's why you see the name of the function instead of a numeric value. I think that's why there is the `x` parameter in `plus`. Just change this line of code to

```
return repeated(add1, y)(x)
```

This will evaluate the return function of `repeated` with the value in x.

So using

`plus(5, 1)`

`>> 6`